# Image with transparent circle inside

Tags: css

[image]

How can I achieve this in pure css? I'm trying to achieve by using pseudo before and after. Maybe some tweaking on the border but I can't think of a way to recreate this.

This is what I have so far: CSS

```css
.imageDiv {
  background-image:url('https://picsum.photos/id/64/4326/2884')
  width: 160px;
  height: 135px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  opacity: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-left: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.imageDiv::after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff61;
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<div class="imageDiv" style="background-image:url('https://picsum.photos/id/64/4326/2884')">
  <label class="imageText">
      Cambiar photo
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `<div class=`, not `<div className=`. You can also probably remove the input tag with no name (and display: none) as that will do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is below, making use of the `mask-image()` CSS property along with a `radial-gradient()` to create the circular shape; the code contains explanatory comments:

```css
:root {
  --main-inline-size: 80%;
  --main-max-inline-size: 1200px;
  --main-min-inline-size: 20rem;
  --spacing: 0.5rem;
}

*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  block-size: 100vh;
  font-family: system-ui;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: var(--spacing);
}

menu,
ol,
ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

main {
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
  inline-size: clamp(var(--main-min-inline-size), var(--main-inline-size), var(--main-max-inline-size));
  margin-inline: auto;
  min-block-size: 100%;
  padding: var(--spacing);
}

/* Everything above/prior to this point is irrelevant to the demo
   and is purely to serve as a simple reset, and base-style */

figure {
  /* in order to use grid-layout, while also retaining an inline
     aspect to allow adjacent content: */
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-rows: fit-content;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

figure > * {
  /* placing all the children of <figure> in the first column
     of the first row: */
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
}

img {
  /* this is for Chrome, and presumably other Chromium-based
     browsers as, despite the comments on both MDN and
     CanIUse (see the links in the "compatibility" section, below)
     it seems that Chrome doesn't (yet) support the non-prefixed
     version of mask-image, unfortunately necessitating the use
     of the prefixed version: */
  -webkit-mask-image: radial-gradient(black 60%, #fffa 60%);
  /* creating the mask, using CSS radial-gradient(),
     from black (the 'transparent'/'clear' central circle)
     to a lightly transparent white color; both color
     stops are at 60% for a transition at that point: */
  mask-image: radial-gradient(black 60%, #fffa 60%);
}

/* largely irrelevant, just for presentation */

figcaption {
  align-self: end;
  backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
  background-color: #fff9;
  padding-block: 0.25rem;
  padding-inline: 0.5rem;
  transition: translate 0.3s linear;
  translate: 0 100%;
}

figure:hover figcaption {
  translate: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <figure>
      <img src="//picsum.photos/400/400" alt="">
    <figcaption>Cambiar photo</figcaption>
  </figure>
</main>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/8ojnkpy1/3/).

I completely failed to notice the centred text in the example, so my updated demo addresses that failure (though I retain a transition, on `clip-path` this time) obviously remove if you don't want one:

```css
:root {
  --main-inline-size: 80%;
  --main-max-inline-size: 1200px;
  --main-min-inline-size: 20rem;
  --spacing: 0.5rem;
}

*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  block-size: 100vh;
  font-family: system-ui;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: var(--spacing);
}

menu,
ol,
ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

main {
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
  inline-size: clamp(var(--main-min-inline-size), var(--main-inline-size), var(--main-max-inline-size));
  margin-inline: auto;
  min-block-size: 100%;
  padding: var(--spacing);
}

figure {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-rows: fit-content;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

figure>* {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
}

img {
  -webkit-mask-image: radial-gradient(black 60%, #fffa 50%);
  mask-image: radial-gradient(black 60%, #fffa 50%);
}

figcaption {
  backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
  background-color: #fff9;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 50% 0, 50% 100%, 50% 100%);
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding-block: 0.25rem;
  padding-inline: 0.5rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  align-self: center;
  text-align: center;
  transition: clip-path 0.3s linear;
}

figure:hover figcaption {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<main>
  <figure>
    <img src="//picsum.photos/400/400" alt="">
    <figcaption>Cambiar photo</figcaption>
  </figure>
</main>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/8ojnkpy1/4/).

---

Following the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77057493/image-with-transparent-circle-inside/77057948?noredirect=1#comment135855075_77057948) left by OP, [Benjoe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17249368/benjoe-carandang), below, and verifying that statement with Chrome 116, on both Ubuntu 23.04 and Android 13:

> I cannot see the circle on your demo and I'm using [Google Chrome].

I've edited the above code snippets (and updated the linked JS Fiddle demos, [[1](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/8ojnkpy1/3/), [2](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/8ojnkpy1/4/)]) to include the prefixed `-webkit-mask-image` property. This has been checked in my installations of Chrome 116 on both platforms available. Feedback would be welcomed if there are other problems.

References:

- [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path).
- [`mask-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-image).
- [`radial-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/css/gradient/radial-gradient).

Compatibility information from:

- [CanIUse.com](https://caniuse.com/?search=mask-image).
- [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-image)

Comment: I cannot see the circle on your demo and I'm using google chrome.

Comment: I never thought to verify with Chrome, according to both MDN and CanIUse (links in the "compatibility" entries) Chrome supported the prefixed `-webkit-mask-image` from version 8, and unspecified "later versions" support the unprefixed version. This is, apparently, incorrect. See the updates, though, in which I've added the prefixed version; which works for me, in Chrome (and also in other browsers that support those properties; including Firefox and Edge).

Answer (score -1):

```css
.imageDiv {
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  position: relative;
  mix-blend-mode: hard-light;
}
.imageDiv img{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.overlay {
  mix-blend-mode: hard-light;
  width: 100%;
  pointer-events: auto;
  inset: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10000;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}
.mask {
  height: 80%;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="imageDiv">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/64/4326/2884" />
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="mask">
      Cambiar photo
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain how this solves the question